# Convert Membership From Manual Renewal To Auto-Renew Without Making A Payment?

Tags: civimember, payment-processor, recurring-contributions, auto-renew, renewals

A client wants to convert a contact's membership from manually renewing to auto-renew. The contact recently made a manual renewal payment but now wants auto-renew enabled without making another payment. Is this possible? My only idea is to give the contact a 100% discount code for 1 year's renewal and have them enable auto-renew when submitting the membership renewal form.